# Progress bar for long running server calls in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I just want to create a progress bar while long running server calls. I could not create a ajax post request to the controller while the controller is doing a long running job.

I want to create an additional action to get the actual statement of current long running task. 
I tried to create poll in ajax request then i can able to return the status from the server side and display it in a client side progress bar. Any ideas ?

Comment: Maybe take a look at SignalR: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh852586.aspx

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The right and easiest way to do this is with SignalR. Please download Microsoft SignalR in https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR/2.1.2

Create a hub class in separate folder in project path called hubs, add two class files into the hubs folder

Startup.cs

```
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalRChat.Startup))]
namespace SignalRChat
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

ProgressHub.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace RealTimeProgressBar
{
    public class ProgressHub : Hub
    {

        public string msg = "Initializing and Preparing...";
        public int count = 1;

        public static void SendMessage(string msg , int count)
        {
            var message = "Process completed for " + msg;
            var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProgressHub>();
            hubContext.Clients.All.sendMessage(string.Format(message), count);
        }

        public void GetCountAndMessage()
        {
            Clients.Caller.sendMessage(string.Format(msg), count);
        }
    }
}
```

In controller,

```
// assemblies
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using RealTimeProgressBar;   


//call this method inside your working action
ProgressHub.SendMessage("initializing and preparing",  2);
```

In View,

```
<!--The jQuery library is required and is referenced by default in _Layout.cshtml. -->
<!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<!--SignalR script to update the chat page and send messages.--> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#progressBar").kendoProgressBar({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        type: "percent",
    });
});

function StartInvoicing()
{
    var progressNotifier = $.connection.progressHub;

    // client-side sendMessage function that will be called from the server-side
    progressNotifier.client.sendMessage = function (message, count) {
        // update progress
        UpdateProgress(message, count);
        //alert(message);
    };

    // establish the connection to the server and start server-side operation
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        // call the method CallLongOperation defined in the Hub
        progressNotifier.server.getCountAndMessage();
    });
}

// Update the progress bar 
function UpdateProgress(message, count) {
    var result = $("#result");
    result.html(message);
    $("#progressBar").data("kendoProgressBar").value(count);
}
</script>
```

For more details refer some existing articles with the help of google

Comment: Is that possible to send the "SendMessage" to just the one client that openned that page?

Comment: where is getCountAndMessage() defined?

Comment: Re: where is getCountAndMessage() defined
GetCountAndMessage() must be a public void method in the ProcessHub-class - intended to start the process I assume.

Comment: Sorry for the delay..I have updated missing part. Please have a look

Comment: Is that possible to send the "SendMessage" to just the one client that openned that page?   Yes. Clients.Client(someConnectionIdIWantToSendToSpecifically).sendMessage(string.Format(message), count);  Then it is not a broadcast

Comment: StartInvoicing(); can be called in (document).ready or user defined call as button click

Comment: I added the SignalR NuGet package, updated it, and I'm getting an error saying SignalRChat is a namespace that cannot be found on the line "[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(SignalRChat.Startup))]"

Comment: @Beau SignalRChat is the namespace. You should replace it with your namespace under which you have Startup.cs

Comment: "//call this method inside your working action
ProgressHub.SendMessage("initializing and preparing",  2);" I am trying to update progress bar for a single user, for a process that goes through several steps. I am calling a controller action. Problems with example: 1) ProgressHub is not a static class; 2) you cannot create a Hub w/ ctor (and have it work); and 3) you cannot get "the" hub (only a context of it) ... even if you could get hub, how do you get the client's Id and target just that client, without a context 'Caller'?

Answer (score 2):

I had a  long running service for that, I have given a basic idea below. Use it as per your requirements.

1. I made a structure of the progress arguments `ProgressArgs`
2. In the long running service LongRunningProcess(), updated the progress values at regular interval and saved in JSON format in the database
3. Created a Action method `getProgress()` which will return a JSON string progress by ajax.
4. Created a function Javascript `getProgress()` function which once started will call the server at regular intervals for progress till the process is completed.

I have given a rough example to implement it. Hope it may help you.

The class for progress arguments structure

```
public class ProgressArgs
{
    public int Completed { get; set; }
    public int Total { get; set; }
    public int Percentage { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

In the Process I kept on updating the stats in the database

```
    public void LongRunningProcess()
    {

        ProgressArgs result = new ProgressArgs();
        result.Completed = 0;
        result.Total = userList.Count;
        foreach (var item in itemList)
        {
           //Do Some processing which u want to do

            result.Total++;
            result.Percentage = (result.Completed * 100) / result.Total;
            result.Status = "Processing";
            string strToSave = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
            //update the strToSave to the database somewhere.
        }

        //after completing of processing
        result.Total++;
        result.Percentage = (result.Completed * 100) / result.Total;
        result.Status = "Completed";
        string strToSave = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
        //update the strToSave to the database somewhere.

    }
```

The C# Action to get the progress by ajax

```
    public string getProgress()
    {    
        string strJSON = config.GetValue("progress");  //Get stats from the database which is saved in json
        return strJSON;
    }
```

The Javascript Code

```
//Ajax Get Progress function
    function getProgress() {
        var dataToSend = '';
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("getProgress")', //Link to the action method
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: dataToSend,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                if (response != null) {
                    data = JSON.parse(response);
                    console.log(data);
                    //update the progressbar
                    progressbar.progressbar("value", data.Percentage);
                    //When the jobalert status is completed clear the interval
                    if (data.Status == 0) {
                        setTimeout(getProgress, 800); //TImout function to call the respective function at that time
                    }
                    serviceCompleted(data); function to call after completing service
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert('Error: There was some error while posting question. Please try again later.');
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: the problem here is, I need to call  getProgress() with form submit       $("#SaveInvoice").submit();                            getProgress();                                                       then getProgress throws and error code 0, not firing the server side call

Comment: does the ajax throws it?

Comment: yes. ajax throws the error code 1. it does not fire the action class.

Comment: try to check the url, from which u are fetching... for me it was that..