# Can jQuery Ajax get updated by the progress of the called webmethod while running?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, webmethod

I have an ajax query calling a Webmethod on the server, the Webmethod does a bunch of stuff and then returns with a value (that I use in the onSuccess part of the ajax)

my question here.. is there a way to notify the client script of the status of the Webmethod while running. i.e. if its running a 100 time loop it would notify at the start of each iteration.

jQuery AJAX:

```
    `$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Whatsapp.aspx/GetProgress",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            // do stuff with result
        },
        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("function error:" + xhr.statusText + "\n" + textStatus + "\n" + errorThrown);
            if (window.console) console.log(xhr);
        }
    });`
```

and the WebMethod on the codebehind:

```
[WebMethod]
public static int GetProgress()
{
    for()
    {
     //notify the client a start of a new iteration?????

     //do lots of stuff here
    }
    //return the end result
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Progress bar for long running server calls in ASP.Net MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27313550/progress-bar-for-long-running-server-calls-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: you may want to look at Signal R