# How to show progress-bar using SignalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

When I'm working with AJAX it is pretty straightforward:

1. Start a progress-bar (like submit button progress-bar)
2. Make an AJAX call
3. When success handler is called, update the UI with the data you've got from AJAX call and stop the progress-bar

When I work with SignalR I do the following. On the server my hub method does not return anything (so I can not update UI and stop a progress-bar). Instead I call a method like ThisDataWasChanged for all clients (including the one that sent the data).

I'm not quite sure what to do. I mean, sure I could first return data for a client that called the hub method and then update all other clients (somehow differentiating them) but it seems such an overkill.

Comment: Please post your code how you are currently doing the progress bar so we can provide a better answer

Comment: Please see this complete answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27526294/2181514

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is something like the following in your Hub class

**Hub**

```
public class ProgressBarHub : Hub
{
    public void change()
    {
        // Do some stuff
        Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).thisDataWasChanged(progressBarObj);   
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
// Create hub
var hub = $.connection.progressBarHub;

// Connect
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    // Start progress bar?
    // Create a start progress bar method in the hub and call it
    });


hub.client.thisDataWasChanged = function (progressBarObj) {
    //Do something to the progress bar with the progressBarObj that we returned 
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately following this implementation all progressbars on all clients will be closed after thisDataWasChanged. There should be a way to find out thisDataWasChanged is caused by a specific client call.

Comment: What do you mean will be closed? You can just send the update to the calling client by using `Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).thisDataWasChanged` instead.

Comment: I ended up passing Context.ConnectionId to thisDataWasChanged and on a client I check if it is my notification and stop progress bar

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help.