# ASP.NET not sending upload progress to client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xmlhttprequest

I am doing an image upload like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (e) {
    // THIS DOESN'T UPDATE UNTIL THE END. EVEN WITH A 10MB IMAGE
}, false);
xhr.open('POST', 'https://www.coolsite.com/api/upload', true);
reader.onload = function (evt) {
    var blob = new Blob([evt.target.result]);
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', blob);
    xhr.send(formData);
};
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```

Then on the server I read it like this:

```
public class VideoController : CORSController
{
    ImageSaver imageSaver = new ImageSaver();
    public HttpResponseMessage Post()
    {
        Stream imageStream = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0].InputStream;
        imageSaver.save(imageStream);
        return new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };
    }
}

public class CORSController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Options()
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };
    }
}
```

But the thing is the client only gets the progress event once the file is done uploading even if I use huge image files. I have looked for an answer to this and tried various configurations for attaching the progress event but nothing works. I think I am doing something wrong on the server.

NOTE - This is a CORS upload so maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: Your server side code doesn't respond with any progress. And % uploaded is not an out of the box feature of mvc. To get a % completed progress value you should probably use SignalR like this Your server side code doesn't respond with any progress. And % uploaded is not an out of the box feature of mvc. To get a % completed progress value you should probably use SignalR like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27526294/623799.

Answer (score 2):

If you have *no error* or *returned status* in browser console, so the problem is not related to server or its configuration. Albeit, I believe that showing the upload progress, **mainly, is a client side issue**. So I exhort you to use a more clean an organized client side code like this one which I write for you:

```
var bar = $('#uploadprogress');//like a <div> which will show the progress
var current = $('#preview');

$('#sendform').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('#progressbar').show();
        var percentVal = '0%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        bar.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        bar.html(percentVal);
    },
    success: function () {
        var percentVal = '100%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        bar.html(percentVal);
    },
    complete: function (xhr) {
        current.html(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

And the **controller** simply looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
     if (file != null)
     {
          string extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower();
          if (extension == ".jpg" || extension == ".png")
          {
               file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(_directory + file.FileName));
               return PartialView("_view");
          }
          else throw new Exception("Not Supported File");
     }
     throw new Exception("Empty File");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding these lines. I usually add them in a .js file loaded in the _layout view so I get the "loading effect" everywhere, otherwise add them just in the page with the file upload.

```
$(document).on({
    ajaxStart: function () { $body.addClass("loading"); },
    ajaxStop: function () { $body.removeClass("loading"); }
});
```

then add the following css class

```
/* Start by setting display:none to make this hidden.
   Then we position it in relation to the viewport window
   with position:fixed. Width, height, top and left speak
   for themselves. Background we set to 80% white with
   our animation centered, and no-repeating */
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 ) url('../Images/Loader.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
/* When the body has the loading class, we turn the scrollbar off with overflow:hidden */
body.loading {
    overflow: hidden;   
}

/* Anytime the body has the loading class, our modal element will be visible */
body.loading .modal {
    display: block;
}
```

And finally choose a loader gif (for example from here http://www.ajaxload.info/)

Answer (score 2):

I have tried like following. It worked for me.

```
xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (e) {
       console.log((e.loaded / e.total * 100).toFixed(2) + '%');
}, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

take a look at this [Uploading files with MVC](http://davidsonsousa.net/en/post/how-to-upload-a-file-using-mvc-3-and-ajax)