# Jquery. Set custom progress text

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to implement a custom text based progress on an ajax post.
When a user clicks on a button and the post is performed I would love to inform the user about the current status. (For example set the text of the button pressed with the current status).

So in the example below the user should be updated four times.

```
public ActionResult DoWork()
    {
      //Create the application pool code
      creating app pool. please wait...

      //Create the website code
      creating website. please wait...

      //Create database code
      creating database. please wait...

      //All done! enjoy new user!!
      job succeeded! Welcome!

      return View();
    }
```

Can I achieve such an effect with jquery? 
Is there anything like `OnChange` that could be usefull?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic **client-to-server** way: client periodically call server -> server returns a status/percentage -> client updates html:

```
var intervalId = setInterval(function () {
$.post("Home/Progress", { id: taskId }, function (progress) {
        if (progress >= 100) {
            updateMonitor(taskId, "Completed");
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        } else {
            updateMonitor(taskId, progress + "%");
        }
    });
}, 100);
```

Good explanation [here](http://blog.janjonas.net/2012-01-02/asp_net-mvc_3-async-jquery-progress-indicator-long-running-tasks).

Modern **server-to-client** solution is [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR). And yes, it is supported in MVC4:

```
while((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    // Send a message to the server
    connection.Send(line).Wait();
}
```

Example: [Progress bar for long running server calls in ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27313550/progress-bar-for-long-running-server-calls-in-asp-net-mvc)