# Display progress bar without using For loop

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, progress-bar

I am taking the backup of my server database and restoring it in local database which takes a bit of time. I am thinking to show the progress bar in the form until the job completes. Since i am not using any For loop in the code i am not able to use progress bar tool.

Is there a way to use progress bar without for loop or any other way instead of using Progress bar ? I am using .Net Windows Forms.

Please let me know.

Comment: This could be helpful [Progress Bar for Long Running Server Calls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27313550/progress-bar-for-long-running-server-calls-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: @PirateX thanks for the reply. I am using Windows forms.

Comment: How are you 'getting' actual progress of the operation?  Since its Winforms you could poll it on a timer every N miliseconds. (If you really don't want a loop)

Comment: @user6144226 In a single button click event i am backing up server DB and restoring it to local DB. I dont know how to track the progress.

Comment: @Raj I do think your first order of business should be figuring out how to track the progress you want to display.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what the BackgroundWorker class is for?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this link will help you
[Monitoring backup/restore](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2343/how-to-monitor-backup-and-restore-progress-in-sql-server/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I am using Postgresql , not MSSQL and also i want the process status through front end.

Comment: @Raj I'm pretty sure you can create plSQL query from front end and get progress:) Just try to find plSQL query to get backup progress for Postgre DB. I don't think you have any other way to do that.

Comment: @Raj look here. It seems Backup process has -progress property. So it is possible to get is [link](https://books.google.ru/books?id=RmpGCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA71&lpg=PA71&dq=postgresql+determine+backup+progress&source=bl&ots=RdP35UZ6-k&sig=O-SqXQQd-YJNsswzaZS3V_J0yog&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiWhN2yn4TNAhXDAJoKHR7IAtQQ6AEIaTAJ#v=onepage&q=postgresql%20determine%20backup%20progress&f=false)