# Razor ajax progress bar with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I'm looking to use the bootstrap progress bar with a Razor ajax form but I'm unsure how to proceed. Whenever I search for the topic, I get results for jquery ajax like this [one](http://burnignorance.com/jquery-performance-tips/bootstrap-progress-bar-with-jquery-ajax/), but not for a Razor ajax form. My Razor form is as follows:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MyAction", null,
new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST", 
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
    UpdateTargetId = "myDiv"
}, new { @class = "form-inline" }))
{
   ...
}
```

Here is with jquery ajax.

```
$.ajax({
 url:"",
 async: true,
 xhr: function () {
      var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
      //Upload Progress
      xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
         if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100; $('div.progress > div.progress-bar').css({ "width": percentComplete + "%" }); } }, false);

//Download progress
 xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt)
 {
 if (evt.lengthComputable)
  { var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total) *100;
 $("div.progress > div.progress-bar").css({ "width": percentComplete + "%" }); } },
false);
return xhr;
},
```

Since Razor doesn't have an ajax option `xhr`, how would I go about accomplishing this behavior?

Comment: This really doesn't have much to do with razor syntax.  In the article you linked, note "However, XMLHttpRequest object exposes an event progress which is triggered after every chuck of data recieved."  In order to use this approace you would need to set up your response to return the result in multiple 'chunks'.  Then, after each chunk, you update the progress.  How to set up the 'chunks' depends greatly on exactly what is being computed.

Comment: Check out this solution.  It's not the same kind of solution you are talking about but it would solve your overall problem:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27313550/progress-bar-for-long-running-server-calls-in-asp-net-mvc