# How to show loading image until save data and redirect to another page by button click in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to show a page loading image until data is saved in the database and the View is redirected to another page when the submit button is clicked. In my View I have a loading image inside a div with id `divLoading`.

I wish to show the loading image until the data is saved and the View redirected to another page by clicking the submit button. I've tried many ways, but it's not working. The View and Controller code is given below.

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveCountry","Country",FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<body class="nav-md" style="color:black">
    <div class="container body">
        <div class="right_col text-center " role="main" style=" height: 680px;">
            <div class="x_panel center" style="width:250px ; ">
                <h2 class="text-center">State Creation</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="container body">
                <div class="x_panel text-left" style="width:250px; color:black">
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend></legend>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.Label("Display Name", new { @class = "control-label" })
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DisplayName, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "Date" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DisplayName)
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.Label("Print Name", new { @class = "control-label" })
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PrintName, new { @class = "form-control", type = "text", id = "Date" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PrintName)
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.Label("Country")
                            @Html.DropDownList("CountryID", null, "Select", new { @class = "form-control required" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CountryID)
                        </div>
                        <div class="row no-print pull-right">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-left" value="Save">Save <i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
                                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="@Url.Action("Index")"><i class="fa "> Details</i></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
      </body>

   <div Id="divLoading">
   <img src="~/images/Img"/>
  }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult SaveCountry(CountryViewModel CVM)
{
    return RedirectToAction("CountryDetails");
}

public ActionResult CountryDetails()
{
    var  objVisitorsList = db.Country.ToList();
    return View(objVisitorsList.ToList());
}
```

It's simple question, but I've tried many javascript codes and it's not working.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27313550/progress-bar-for-long-running-server-calls-in-asp-net-mvc.. hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, and I'll suggest one that should get you started off:-

(i) Assign a unique id to your form (eg `form-id`) by changing your form code to:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveCountry", "Country", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form-id" })) {
}
```

(ii) Put the loader on your page with a unique id (I've changed your code for the loader, which won't work properly: your didn't close the div and assigned "Id" instead of "id"). The div is hidden until the form is submitted:

```
<div id="divLoading" hidden>
    <img src="path/to/your/image/loading-image.png" />
</div>
```

(iii) Style the loading div to go somewhere useful. This example css centers the div:

```
#divLoading{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: -moz-translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

(iv) Reference some script (I've assumed you're using jQuery here) to show the loader when the form is submitted (and after any validation has been completed), for example:

```
<script>
    $("#form-id").on("submit", function () {
        $("#divLoading").show();
    });
</script>
```

(v) Given that your page will redirect, you can probably leave the loader until the page redirects, but if you need to hide the loader before that happens, you can use:

```
$("#divLoading").hide();
```

on some event to hide the loader, and for it to be ready for the next form submit.

Answer (score 0):

Use Ajax Form Here is sample code:

View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveCountry","Country",   new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "onSuccess", LoadingElementId = "divLoading" },new { @id = "countryForm" })){
<div>
Form Elements....
</div>
<div id="divLoading">
   <img src="~/images/Img"/>
</div>
}
```

In Javascript:

```
var onSuccess = function(result) {
    if (result.url) {
       window.location.href = result.url;
    }
}
```

In Controller:

```
public ActionResult SaveCountry(CountryViewModel CVM)
{
    return Json(new { url = Url.Action("CountryDetails") });
}
```