# Tracking Progress for executed actions MVC and SinglaR

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have a problem. I am doing exactly as mentioned here: [Progress bar for long running server calls in ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27313550/progress-bar-for-long-running-server-calls-in-asp-net-mvc), but it's not working. There is no exceptions nor errors, the problem is that is not doing anything. Why is not my code reporting the progress to the client side? Another thing is that i don't know why signalR does not generate the script

```
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

controller

```
ProgressHub.SendMessage("Iniciando proceso", 2);
```

startup class

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;


[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(DimexCEUI.Startup))]
namespace DimexCEUI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            //ConfigureAuth(app);
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

my hub

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace DimexCEUI
{
    public class ProgressHub : Hub
    {

        public string msg = "Initializing and Preparing...";
        public int count = 1;

        public static void SendMessage(string msg, int count)
        {
            var message = "Proceso completado " + msg;
            var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProgressHub>();
            hubContext.Clients.All.sendMessage(string.Format(message), count);
        }

        public void GetCountAndMessage()
        {
            Clients.Caller.sendMessage(string.Format(msg), count);
        }
    }
}
```

Client:

```
function StartInvoicing() {
    var progressNotifier = $.connection.progressHub;

    // client-side sendMessage function that will be called from the server-side
    progressNotifier.client.sendMessage = function (message, count) {
        // update progress
        UpdateProgress(message, count);
        alert(message);
    };

    // establish the connection to the server and start server-side operation
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        // call the method CallLongOperation defined in the Hub
        progressNotifier.server.getCountAndMessage();
    });
}

// Update the progress bar 
function UpdateProgress(message, count) {
    var result = $("#progress-data");
    result.html(message);
    $("#progress-count").html(count);
}
```

Comment: The selected answer is not complete. Nothing calls `StartInvoicing` so the client is never registered

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto good answer. It works thanks

Comment: I don't understand - from where is 'StartInvoicing' called?