# How can i create signalR progress bar in Asp.net Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

I am converting pdf documents into JPG. the document list i get is random sometimes conversion takes more time sometime less, depends on number of files and there size.

I want to give user visual notification that conversion is going on and it is converting abc.pdf. 
So i came up on this concept of signalR. which allows us to send server side data to client. this is a great concept. But i know very little about signalR and also i found a example project that is in MVC. i know webforms only.

I have for loop for the number of files.so i get total count and current converting document number.

I expect to have a model popup with progress bar on it that will show the progress. how can i achieve that?

Comment: Check [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1124691/SignalR-Progress-Bar-Simple-Example-Sending-Live-D). It may help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Progress bar for long running server calls in ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27313550/progress-bar-for-long-running-server-calls-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: It is in MVC. I need in ASP .NET C# webforms.